# How to get specific data from an array of objects in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm trying to get the ID's from the selected items in my PrimeNG DataTable. I'm getting this error but I can't find too much about in on Google...

```
ERROR in C:/Users/*****/Documents/Octopus/Octopus 2.0/src/app/gebruikers/gebruikers.component.ts (200,33): Type must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.)
```

This is my 'interface':

```
export interface Departement {
DepName;
ID;
}
```

This is my html code:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="departementen" [rows]="3" class="thumbnail" resizableColumns="true" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="0" 
            [rowsPerPageOptions]="[3,5,10]" [globalFilter]="gbDepartementen" emptyMessage=""
            [(selection)]="NGSelectedDepartementen">
            <p-column [style]="{'width':'30px'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
            <p-column [style]="{'width':'40px'}" field="ID" header="ID"></p-column>
            <p-column field="DepName" header="Departement"></p-column>
        </p-dataTable>
```

This is my component code how I want it to work, but it doesn't... (of course)

```
NGSelectedDepartementen: Departement;
for (let x of this.NGSelectedDepartementen) {
                console.log(x.ID);
}
```

This is what's in my NGSelectedDepartementen when I select two 'departementen':

```
Array[2]
0:Object
DepName:"Koninklijke Academie voor Schone Kunsten Antwerpen"
  ID:16
  __proto__:Object
1:Object
  DepName:"Koninklijk Conservatorium Antwerpen"
  ID:17
  __proto__:Object
length:2
__proto__:Array[0]
```

Can anyone give me some example code for how I should do this?

### Answer

Your NGSelectedDepartementen should be of type `Departement[]` instead of `Departement`. Except if the Departement instance is a class instance that implements the Iterable interface.

`NGSelectedDepartementen: Departement[];`

Answer by n00dl3

Comment: I am more interested in knowing what you get on `console.log(this.NGSelectedDepartementen)`

Comment: Yeah at the moment nothing because the app won't run. "webpack: Failed to compile"

Comment: can you share the log and other details becoz unless you tell what is exactly there in `NGSelectedDepartementen`, it would be hard to get to a solution.

Comment: I added what's inside `NGSelectedDepartementen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `NGSelectedDepartementen` should be of type `Departement[]` instead of `Departement`. Except if the `Departement` instance is a class instance that implements the `Iterable` interface.

```
NGSelectedDepartementen: Departement[];
```